# CRLF not found before max message length: 2048 with payload-deserializing-transformer

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using payload-deserializer-transformer in my TCP client as follows.

```
    <context:property-placeholder />

<int:gateway id="gw"
    service-interface="myGateway"
    default-request-channel="objectIn"
    default-reply-channel="objectOut" />

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
    type="client"
    host="${client.server.TCP.host}"
    port="${client.server.TCP.port}"
    single-use="true"
    so-timeout="10000" />

<int:channel id="objectIn" />

<int:payload-serializing-transformer input-channel="objectIn" output-channel="bytesOut"/>

<int:channel id="bytesOut" />   

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
    request-channel="bytesOut"
    reply-channel="bytesIn"
    connection-factory="client"
    request-timeout="10000"
    reply-timeout="10000" />

<int:channel id="bytesIn" />

<int:payload-deserializing-transformer input-channel="bytesIn" output-channel="objectOut" />

<int:channel id="objectOut" />
```

The above works fine for message length < 2048 but if the message exceeds this limit I get following error.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CRLF not found before max message length: 2048
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer.fillToCrLf(ByteArrayCrLfSerializer.java:66)
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer.deserialize(ByteArrayCrLfSerializer.java:44)
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayCrLfSerializer.deserialize(ByteArrayCrLfSerializer.java:31)
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.getPayload(TcpNetConnection.java:120)
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpMessageMapper.toMessage(TcpMessageMapper.java:113)
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.run(TcpNetConnection.java:165)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I set maxMessageSize property on the payload-deserializing-transformer in this case?

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the transformer; the error is in the outbound gateway.

First of all, you should not be using text-based delimiting for inbound TCP messages; a serialized object contains binary data and might contain CRLF (0x0d0a) somewhere in the middle.

You should be using one of the binary-capable deserializers in the gateway.

You can read about TCP serializers/deserializers in the [reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories).

You should configure the outbound gateway to use a `ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer` in the `serializer` and `deserializer` attributes; it can handle binary payloads.

The remote system will also need to be changed to use a length header instead of using CRLF to detect the end of a message. If the remote system is also Spring Integration, simply change its serializer/deserializer too.

For other readers who are using text-based messaging, the `ByteArrayCrlfSerializer` can be configured with a `maxMessageSize` which defaults to 2048.

The `ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer` also has a `maxMessageSize` (also 2048) which is configurable - this is to prevent OOM conditions when a bad message is received.